# Python efficiency for iterating through large lists/arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I will be attaching a client to listen in on an OPC server comprising of thousands of nodes that reads mechanical data from various sensors. The code for the client will be written in some version of Python3.

So essentially, the task comes down to:

1. Connect to the server endpoint
2. Iterate through all the nodes and pick up its values from the server
3. Store the read values in some format (not decided yet)

I've written a basic sample code, just to add some reference:

```
import sys 
import time
import datetime 
import asyncio 
import json 
from opcua import Client 

endpoint = "opc.tcp://some-server-endpoint:portid/foobar"

# In actual DEV code, there will be about 100_000 nodes. 
# Will make reading the nodes into a separate loop function
# to avoid hard coding all the node IDs. 
nodes = [
    "i=1001", 
    "i=1002", 
    "i=1003"
]

# Connect to Endpoint (Probably will wrap this into a
# function in DEV as well but need to look at how the
# library dependencies handle the connection)
try:
    server = Client(endpoint)
    server.connect()
    print("Connection Success.")
except Exception as err:
    print("Connection Error:", err)
    sys.exit(1)

# Function to return node values, nodeID and timestamp
async def read_node(arg) -> str:
    node_conn = server.get_node(arg)
    node_value = node_conn.get_value()
    output = {
        "nodeID": str(arg),
        "value": str(node_value),
        "timestamp": str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
    }
    global output_log
    output_log = json.dumps(output)
    print(output_log)

# Returns output to JSON file (For the sake of practice,
# just made it to dump all outputs into a single JSON
# file for now)
def json_convert(data) -> str: 
    with open("opc_data.json", "a") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2)

# Loops through nodes list, outputs to json file
async def main() -> None:
        while True: 
            for i in range(len(nodes)):
                async_read = await read_node(nodes[i])
                json_convert(output_log)
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I am not looking for a code review (although all suggestions are welcome!!).

My primary question is how to maximize the efficiency of having to loop through thousands of items in the form of a `list` or `array` when data needs to be read consistently and constantly on 1 sec intervals or less.

In the above code, I used async so that each batch of data can be stored independently and together in various storage locations, but there seems to be other options such as multiprocessing or threading also available.

Each option seems to have its pros and cons, and I am not sure how many cores I can end up using for this job which could make things like multiprocessing less efficient.

Currently, the only thing I can think of is maybe using a library like numpy to take advantage of something like `np.array`.

Comment: It seems to me that you're going in the right direction.
You can iterate directly on the nodes instead of using an index, by replacing `for i in range(len(nodes))` by `for node in nodes`.
You can improve the solution by making also asynchronous the output. As storing to a file is still I/O to disk.
I'm not sure at all that numpy will be of any help for this use case.
If you encounter performance issues maybe (if possible) you can try a sharding strategy, e.g. run 4 processes of your program each one dedicated to one quarter of your nodes.

Comment: Your concern about the "thing" you are iterating over is unfounded.  Right now, you are iterating over a generator.  It's not going to get any faster, and iterating over thousands or millions of items is almost instantaneous for an empty loop.  You need to be more concerned about your output.  Right now you are opening and closing a file **for each node** which is going to be awfully slow!